# Change the position of a button to up

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a logo a dropdown menu and a search bar the problem is that dropdown button it's down and I want it to up.
I have this way:
[image]

But I want something like this where button is align with the logo and search bar: 
[image]

I have tried a lot of things like call the class of button in css and put margin-button with a lot of pxls but its work, any suggestion?
This is my code HTMl where I have the button:

```
        <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-left" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo-01.png" style="max-width:70px"/></a>
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
                    <button type ="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>    

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div class="cd-dropdown-wrapper">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cd-dropdown-trigger">Categorias</button>

                <nav class="cd-dropdown">

            <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
            <ul class="cd-dropdown-content">

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=748">Eletrodomésticos</a>

                    <ul class="cd-secondary-dropdown is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=748">Todos os eletrodomésticos</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=748">Eletrodomésticos</a>

                            <ul class="is-hidden">
                                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Eletrodomésticos</a></li>
                                <li class="see-all"><a href="http://codyhouse.co/?p=748">Todos os eletrodomésticos</a></li>
                                <!--<li class="has-children">-->
                                <li><a href="#0">Grandes Eletro de cozinha</a></li>

 ....<!--(has other categories but it doesnt matter for here so I skip that part)-->

                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar Produto">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

This is my css code:

```
.btn-default {
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  background: #25727D;
  border-color: #25727D;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML to show [mcve]

Comment: can you share entire header html??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I already updated the code with the most important part. Here is the link with the entire html code https://pastebin.com/q9EE2h6U

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai if you need the css code completed please tell me.

Comment: add valid required html to solve problem and also the required css.

Comment: @amit77309 what is valid required html?

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn-default {
            margin-bottom:350px;
            background: #25727D;
            border-color: #25727D;
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:50px;
        }
```

Since `.btn-default` already have `position:absolute`, just change `top:10px` or `top:desiredValue` accordingly to change vertical position of button.

Comment: It didnt work. when I wrote top with some value the button was down and when I put bottom the button stay at the same level and doesnt went up.